# .htaccess and .htpassword not working

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm running a wamp server on a windows xp box.

I have a .htaccess file that contains

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile C:/wamp/www/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

and a password file .htpasswd

```
user:$apr1$4EPQ5/..$aRu05NnKW3Zhpf2m1Jst2.
```

password = password

The .htaccess file sits in a subdir called "NewCats" (the folder im trying to protect) and the password file sits in the root dir (i tried it in the newcats folder and it didn't work there either.

the document root is

C:/wamp/www/

so what am i doing wrong?
(also i used this site to create the hashes http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is the following :

On Windows the paths use a backslash (`\`) and not a slash (`/`).

Try editing your `.htaccess` to match this.

```
AuthUserFile C:\wamp\www\.htpasswd
```

You also have to be sure that `auth_basic_module` is activated in Apache and that your `.htaccess` doesn't end with the `txt` extension !

Comment: sorry about the delay but  auth_basic_module is in place (the page does prompt me) and ive reveresed the slashes and it diffiently doesnt end in .txt  but im still not getting in with the name and password

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `AllowOverride None` isn't set. It ignores .htaccess files that way. Make it read `AllowOverride AuthConfig`.